# Behavior of core dump. is defined or undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, coredump

In the below code, i made a mistake by giving the buffer size small.

```
char request[10];
```

While reading from file i used the fscanf and my line in file was "THIS_IS_THE_TEST_CODE". Here the line length is more than size of buffer.

But below are some scenarios where my code executed successfully without core dump even though the buffer size was small.

Scenario 1:

I have commented the line

```
class_test *c = class_test :: getinstance();
```

At that time code executed successfully without dump.

Scneario 2:
After finding the bug, i increased the buffer size, it worked for all cases.

But the pstack core shown at feof

```
 fefabfe0 feof     (1, ffbff9c4, ffbff9cc, 212e4, ff390100, 0)
 00010940 _start   (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) + 5c
```

Why such behavoiur of the code?

Environment: UNIX SOLARIS

```
 class class_test
     {
        public:

           static class_test* getinstance()
           {
              static class_test single_obj;
              return &single_obj;
           }

     };


     #include<iostream>

         int main()
         {
            using namespace std;
            class_test *c = class_test :: getinstance();

            FILE  *fptr;
            char request[10];

            if((fptr  = fopen("inputstat.txt","r")) == NULL)
            {
               printf("Couldn't Open..");
            }
            else
            {

           while(!feof(fptr))
           {
              memset(request,'\0',sizeof(request));
              fscanf(fptr,"%s",request);

           }
        }
        return 0;
     }
```

Comment: "Undefined behaviour" means "Anything can happen, including the code working as designed". It's advisable to not rely on undefined behaviour doing what you want however, as it's free to switch to "Not working" at any point. Basically, you're getting lucky with how memory is being laid out "under the hood": this can change as your program does, OS updates or even throughout the course of the day. Someone else can answer with specifics, but the short answer is "If your buffer is smaller than your data, you can't predict what your program will do in all cases"

Comment: `But below are some scenarios where my code executed successfully without core dump even though the buffer size was small.`  Writing beyond the boundaries of an array is `undefined behavior`.  A program that overwrites memory may run, may crash, may run sometimes and crash other times, may run on your machine but crash on someone elses machine, may run for years without issue and then crash with a slight change in the code that has nothing to do with the buffer in question, etc.